# Correctly piping input into grep and performing regex on it for digits and matched string

Tags: regex, grep

I have a script that outputs the following output:

> Overall Status - OK (Sample Period 9 sec) -  Physical Drive Name="0
>   C:" (OK) - _PercentIdleTime=100%, _PercentBusyTime=0%,
>   _PercentDiskTime=1%, _PercentDiskReadTime=0%, _PercentDiskWriteTime=1%, _DiskReadBytesPersec=0.000B/sec, _DiskReadsPersec=0.000/sec, _DiskWriteBytesPersec=0.00MB/sec, _DiskWritesPersec=8.000/sec, CurrentDiskQueueLength=0, _AvgDiskQueueLength=0.0, _AvgDiskReadQueueLength=0.0, _AvgDiskWriteQueueLength=0.0|'_PercentIdleTime0 C:'=100; '_PercentBusyTime0 C:'=0; '_PercentDiskTime0 C:'=1;
>   '_PercentDiskReadTime0 C:'=0; '_PercentDiskWriteTime0 C:'=1;
>   '_DiskReadBytesPersec0 C:'=0; '_DiskReadsPersec0 C:'=0;
>   '_DiskWriteBytesPersec0 C:'=71917; '_DiskWritesPersec0 C:'=8;
>   'CurrentDiskQueueLength0 C:'=0; '_AvgDiskQueueLength0 C:'=0.0;
>   '_AvgDiskReadQueueLength0 C:'=0.0; '_AvgDiskWriteQueueLength0 C:'=0.0;

Using grep I'd like to filter out everything but **_DiskWriteBytesPersec=0.00MB**

I used the following regex on http://regexr.com/ to successfully doing so:
**(_DiskWriteBytesPersec=(\d*)?.(\d*)MB)**

But I'm having difficulties getting it to work with grep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your regular expression was `(_DiskWriteBytesPersec=(\d*)?.(\d*)MB)` that it does not support `\d` instead use `[0-9]`, You can try this, it will work fine.

```
echo "Overall Status - OK (Sample Period 9 sec) - Physical Drive Name="0 C:" (OK) - _PercentIdleTime=100%, _PercentBusyTime=0%, _PercentDiskTime=1%, _PercentDiskReadTime=0%, _PercentDiskWriteTime=1%, _DiskReadBytesPersec=0.000B/sec, _DiskReadsPersec=0.000/sec, _DiskWriteBytesPersec=0.00MB/sec, _DiskWritesPersec=8.000/sec, CurrentDiskQueueLength=0, _AvgDiskQueueLength=0.0, _AvgDiskReadQueueLength=0.0, _AvgDiskWriteQueueLength=0.0|'_PercentIdleTime0 C:'=100; '_PercentBusyTime0 C:'=0; '_PercentDiskTime0 C:'=1; '_PercentDiskReadTime0 C:'=0; '_PercentDiskWriteTime0 C:'=1; '_DiskReadBytesPersec0 C:'=0; '_DiskReadsPersec0 C:'=0; '_DiskWriteBytesPersec0 C:'=71917; '_DiskWritesPersec0 C:'=8; 'CurrentDiskQueueLength0 C:'=0; '_AvgDiskQueueLength0 C:'=0.0; '_AvgDiskReadQueueLength0 C:'=0.0; '_AvgDiskWriteQueueLength0 C:'=0.0;" | grep -Eo "_DiskWriteBytesPersec=[0-9]*?.[0-9]+MB";
```

Pipe your output with `grep -Eo "_DiskWriteBytesPersec=[0-9]*?.[0-9]+MB"`

**Command output:** `_DiskWriteBytesPersec=0.00MB`

> **1.** `E` for extended Regular Expression.
>
> **2.** `O` for outputting only matched string.